# Rotate Bootstrap dropdown caret on toggle and prevent close if clicked inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following snippet that rotates `.caret` on a `dropdown-toggle` click. This rotates the `.caret` without issue, however it also rotates all of the other `.caret` on the page. Will I need to write a click function for every individual `.caret` and `.dropdown-toggle` on the page or can I have one that works independently?

Also, is there a way in which I can stop the `dropdown-menu` closing when and item within it has been clicked?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".caret").toggleClass('rotate-180');
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.caret {
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.rotate-180 {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: "is there a way in which I can stop the dropdown-menu closing when and item within it has been clicked?" If user clicks on `a` element you want dropdown to remain open?

Comment: @ovokuro that's correct thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See below it works

**Edit**:

I updated my answer to a more better approach to cover all scenarios, and for the last thing you have asked in your OP about preventing the menu to close, can be done in 2 ways

1. Bind `click` event to the `dropdown` and prevent propagation if it is already open.
2. You have to remove the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute and implement open and closing of the menu yourself. But I think that would require more lines of code than the one used in the code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.caret').toggleClass('rotate-180');
  });

  $('.dropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.caret').toggleClass('rotate-180');
  });

  //this is to avoid the menu from closing if clicked inside the menu 
  $('body').on("click", ".dropdown-menu", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().is(".open") && e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.caret {
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.rotate-180 {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way it can rotate when the user clicks on an `<a>` aswell?

Comment: it is rotating on the `<a>` tag , which `<a>` tag are you talking about, currently it works both for the caret and text which are indie the anchor tag with class `dropdown-toggle`

Comment: When I click on one of the list items it does not rotate the caret back round again.

Comment: Hmm it's almost there its just the other dropdown .carets are not rotating when I click away from them. So if I click on the bottom dropdown and the top dropdown is open I would expect the top to close and caret to rotate

Comment: @CBreeze sorry for replying late but I updated my answer to a more better approach which will cover all aspects, hope that covers all your concerns.

Comment: AND , now you can select it as the correct answer too, i deserve it :P.

Answer (score 10):

in bootstrap +v4 just add style:

```css
.dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
transform: rotate(180deg); 
}
/*for animation*/ 
.dropdown-toggle:after { 
transition: 0.7s; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>



            <li class="nav-item dropdown" >
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdowns" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdowns">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
          </li>



    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html><!-- roiket -->
```

Answer (score 2):

In bootstrap 3 whenever you click on the dropdown list when it's opening, class="open" appears so I tried this code and it worked just fine!

```
.open>a>.caret{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all ease-out 0.4s;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click( function(){   
      $(this).children(".caret").toggleClass('rotate-180');     
    });  
});
$(document).on("click", function(event){
  var $trigger = $(".caret");
  if($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length){
     $(".caret").removeClass('rotate-180');  
  }            
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.caret {
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.rotate-180 {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function () { 
   $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click( function() {
       $(this).children(".caret").toggleClass('rotate-180');
     });
    $( ".dropdown-menu" ).click( function() {
       $(this).siblings().children(".caret").toggleClass('rotate-180');
     });
   $(document).click(function(e){
      if(!e.target.closest("ul") && $(".caret").hasClass("rotate-180")){
         $(".caret").removeClass('rotate-180');
      }
    })
 });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () { 
   $( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click( function() {
    $(this).children(".caret").toggleClass('rotate-180');
  });
    $( ".dropdown-menu" ).click( function() {
    $(this).siblings().children(".caret").toggleClass('rotate-180');
  });
   $(document).click(function(e){
      if(!e.target.closest("ul") && $(".caret").hasClass("rotate-180")){
         $(".caret").removeClass('rotate-180');
      }
    })
 });
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.caret {
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.rotate-180 {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> Directories <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```